# Git - how to directly edit a previously staged hunk?

Tags: git, version-control, patch

I've just done a `git add -i` on a file with a lot of changes, and realised I accidentally staged one hunk that I didn't intend to.

How can I un-stage this hunk, without having to repeat the entire `add` and reselect all of the other hunks that I *did* want to commit?

Comment: Do you know of interactive reset (`git reset -p`)? Works like interactive staging (`git add -p`), but in reverse.

Comment: `:O` No I didn't - thank you! `git reset -p` does exactly what I want `:)`

Comment: @jubobs I just love this. Thanks for the hint, should have been a proper answer.

Comment: There's also `git checkout -p` which discards changes in the working tree